# Can someone tell me what Date Time format this string is

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I am being passed this, 2022-11-01T00:00:00, Date Time as a string.  I need to convert it to a DateTime in C# but cannot seem to figure out what exact format the string is in.

I have tried many variations of the following but continue to get String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Here is the latest code I have tried:

```
DateTime test = DateTime.ParseExact(startTime, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This appears to be with how the data is being sent to my software.  I tried the suggestions below but am still receiving the same error message.

Comment: Did you try `var test = DateTime.Parse(dateString);`?

Comment: FYI: the timestamp is in (ISO 8601)[https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html] format

Comment: The answers work, [as demonstrated on dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6ggvBW) (and https://dotnetfiddle.net/rbbTtH). If it is not working in your case, then there is something else going on that you are not sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an offset you are trying to account for? I noticed you have a Z at the end of your DateTime format in the latest code you have tried. Removing it in this block of code made it parseable.

```
string startTime = "2022-11-01T00:00:00";
DateTime test = DateTime.ParseExact(startTime, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString()); // 11/1/2022 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

```
string text = "2022-11-01T00:00:00";

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out DateTime dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("u"));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("bad");
}
```